# unlock the only MySQL account

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

By accident I locked my root account in MySQL which I launch using wamp server, the error message from phpMyAdmin is

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. Account is locked.

How can I unlock this account, all I could find online was assuming that I have another unlocked account.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method from [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Create an `C:\\init.sql` file containing

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' ACCOUNT UNLOCK
```

In the `my.ini` file

```
[mysqld]
init-file=C:\\init.sql
```

Restart the service, check you can access the root user, and then remove `init.sql` file and backout `my.ini` change.

per [`ALTER USER` docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html)